# Android TextView Multiple Strokes

Tags: android, textview, stroke

Is there a way to successfully give the text of a TextView 2 strokes instead of just one? I can do one successfully, but my search is coming up empty for 2.

Comment: You might consider explaining what you mean by "stroke" in the context of a `TextView`. Do you mean that you want a drop-shadow on the text?

Comment: My apologizes, I am trying to have 2 outlines on the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this StrokedTextView class in the AOSP

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/55d225d/src/com/android/launcher2/StrokedTextView.java

It overrides OnDraw to allow as many strokes as you want.